# Prolog fact with a string consisting of letters and numbers not working

Tags: prolog

I have a fact in the format:

```
noun('08226txt').
```

and want it to work like my other facts such as

```
noun(directory).
noun(file).
noun(detail).
```

I can get it to work. It doesn't work without quotations and I'm sure its because its a string consisting of both letter and numbers. This is the error that is produced:

```
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: [the,command,types,the,file,0822
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: 6txt] .
```

Any help appreciated, thankyou.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. `08226txt` simply isn't a valid atom in Prolog without the quotes. The quotes are needed any time you start the atom with something other than a lower case letter, or if the atom contains any other special characters, even spaces. So for example, if you want `foo bar` as an atom, it must be in quotes: `noun('foo bar').` If it contains numbers, but doesn't start with them then you don't need the quotes. `abc123` is a valid atom without the quotes.

Comment: Yeah sorry its a bit vague, thank you for your answer. How come I get an error then if I have used quotes?

Comment: If you're using quotes, you shouldn't be seeing an error. I'm able to asser the fact `noun('08226txt').` in SWI Prolog without a problem.